# Url containing reserve keyword is working with backslash at the end only

Tags: .net, web, url, path

I'm not getting what's the reason that the below URL is valid

```
https://localhost:44372/api/Address/GetCustomerInformation/test@gmail.com/
```

and the following URL are invalid, getting 404.

```
https://localhost:44372/api/Address/GetCustomerInformation/test@gmail.com
https://localhost:44372/api/Address/GetCustomerInformation/test%40gmail.com
```

I check the path section but I didn't get/understood the reason for the same
here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3

Note
Project is in .net,
Route path [Route("GetCustomerInformation/{externalId?}/")]

Demo code

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Address")]
public class AddressController : ApiController
{
   [Route("GetCustomerInformation/{externalId?}")]
   public IHttpActionResult GetBillingAddress(string externalId = null)
   {
         return Ok("Hello");
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I added the sample code. Hope that will help. @StephenOstermiller